# Deny direct access to folder but allow my own website? (htaccess)

Tags: image, apache, access-control

How can i deny (deny from all) a whole subfolder (direct access) but allow to include on my own website without getting error 403.

Example:
Deny from all to 'includes' (all files) but so that i can include the files on my own pages 'sub.domain.tld'. ex. an images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Forbidding Image "Hotlinking"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images)

Comment: Can this be used also for for pdf files? I wan't all files in this folder blocked with error 403 if not includes from my site?